# oracle: Add constraint that checks column for existing value

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, alter-table

I'd like to add a constraint to a column that prevents a new row insertion if the value to be added to that column doesn't exist already. I've been at it for a while, this isn't my current code but I wanted it to be clear what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
ALTER TABLE emps
 ADD CONSTRAINT department_id_ck 
 WHERE department_id = 10 | 20 | 50 | 60 | 80 | 90 | 110;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about making a unique key on the column and you should be through

Comment: "Where is doesn't exist already"?  That is an unusual requirement.  Could you show some sample data along with insertions that would and would not succeed.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for future posts Gordon, I'm still figuring out the protocol here at stack.

Comment: "prevent ... if the value doesn't exist already" implies a referential constraint to a parent table that holds the valid values. A check constraint can't query the table to see if the value exists or not.

Comment: I'll be more careful with my verbiage, thanks for pointing that out jeffrey

Comment: Jeffrey wasn't complaining about your verbiage - he was pointing out that you're asking for the wrong thing. This means that you should possibly reconsider your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of playing this is the statement that I was looking for...

```
ALTER TABLE emps
 ADD CONSTRAINT department_id_ck CHECK (department_id IN (10, 20, 50, 60, 80, 90, 110));
```